# How to setup facebook-php-sdk3 in cakephp-2.0?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, facebook-php-sdk

I need the info about any complete tutorial about how to setup facebook-php-sdk3 in cakephp-2.0. If you have any please help me out of this. I've searched and found some plugins but with incomplete tutorial. So I need a complete tutorial about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might help you get started. Check [cakePHP 2.0 Facebook Plugin](http://www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/243/CakePHP_2_0_Facebook_Plugin_BETA).